# jQuery slideDown and slideUp are not smooth on mobile

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I can,t seems to find any solution to my problem. I am building a web app for mobile. I am using jquery.1.9.1 version. The sliding is smooth on browser but when deploy and check it on mobile browser, it is very laggy. I have tried using easing plugins but it does not solve my problem.

Please, is there anyone out there who can help me?

Comment: Maybe the CPUs in the systems you have tested are too slow?

Comment: The mobile is Dual core Android. it should be fast, but not.

Comment: I have had good results using animate.css (http://daneden.me/animate/) on mobile phone. It is dead simple using this (it is just a css file) along with jQuery `addClass` to produce smooth effect.

Comment: @JofryHS Thank you for your link, but can I find slideDown and slideUp just like jQuery but smooth?

Comment: As I mentioned, I had good experience with it. Here is the fiddle using animate.css: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktv7j/

Comment: have you tested it on multiple browser? like the default one vs Chrome for mobile? I also remember that replacing the SlideUp and SlideDown functions by Animate() fixed the studdering problem a couple of times for me

Comment: @JofryHS, that was a very good suggestion. Tried it on NewsMute (https://github.com/Adimpression/NewsMuteWWW/blob/master/css/animate.css)  and worked on Android like a charm.